# Start New Intent in Android within public void onClick

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start a new Intent but
**new Intent(BuyTicket.this, BusPurchase.class);** is highlighted in red and says: "The constructor Intent(BuyTicket, Class) is undefined"

I've searched stackoverflow for similar problems but none of the solutions to those work.

Thanks!

```
package fyp.sbarcoe.tabsswipe;

public class BuyTicket extends Fragment 
{
ImageButton dubBus, luas, dart ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);   
    dubBus = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
    luas = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.luas);
    dart = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dart);

    dubBus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v)
    {
        System.out.println("Dublin Bus");
        Intent i = new Intent(BuyTicket.this, BusPurchase.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }}); 
    luas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Luas");}}); 
    dart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Dart");}});                 
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Intent i = new Intent(BuyTicket.this, BusPurchase.class);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BusPurchase.class);
```

`Intent` needs an `Activity` in the constructor not a `Fragment` which is what `BuyTicket.this` would refer to

[See the Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 2):

> `new Intent(BuyTicket.this.getActivity(), BusPurchase.class)`

You need to get the activity of the fragment. Try the code above instead.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(BuyTicket.this.getActivity(), BusPurchase.class);
startActivity(i);

This should start the activity (BusPurchase). What happens? What kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Your onCLickListner is an anonymous class.  Try making Context visible:

```
Context mContext;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) 
{
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);   
dubBus = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dubBus);
luas = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.luas);
dart = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dart);

mContext = getApplicationContext();

dubBus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v)
{
    System.out.println("Dublin Bus");
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, BusPurchase.class);
    startActivity(i);
}}); 
luas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Luas");}}); 
dart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){System.out.println("Dart");}});                 
return rootView;
```

}

Comment: getApplicationContext() is underlined and has error:
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: then save a Context in onCreateView and use that. I'll edit my code above to demonstrate